# Duplicate Identifier when local node types are installed

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am trying to run `tsc` on a project, but I am getting an error saying that there are two duplicated identifiers `URL` and `URLSearchParams`.

I have typescript installed globally, and in my project I have `@types/node`.

However when I install `@types/node` in the project I then get this error:

```
../../../../../.nvm/versions/node/v10.0.0/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2016.full.d.ts(13404,11): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'URL'.
../../../../../.nvm/versions/node/v10.0.0/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2016.full.d.ts(13420,13): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'URL'.
../../../../../.nvm/versions/node/v10.0.0/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2016.full.d.ts(13427,11): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'URLSearchParams'.
../../../../../.nvm/versions/node/v10.0.0/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2016.full.d.ts(13454,13): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'URLSearchParams'.
../../../../../.nvm/versions/node/v10.0.0/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2016.full.d.ts(15740,13): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'URL'.
../../../../../.nvm/versions/node/v10.0.0/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2016.full.d.ts(15741,13): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'URLSearchParams'.
../../../../../.nvm/versions/node/v10.0.0/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2016.full.d.ts(16503,11): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'URLSearchParams'.
node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(2381,15): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'URL'.
node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(2399,15): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'URLSearchParams'.
node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(2417,14): error TS2661: Cannot export 'URL'. Only local declarations can be exported from a module.
node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(2417,19): error TS2661: Cannot export 'URLSearchParams'. Only local declarations can be exported from a module.
```

Not sure what is wrong and why I am getting this error.

If I remove the `node types` from my project I get an error in other dependencies saying that it cannot find `net`, `http`, etc:

```
node_modules/@types/uuid/interfaces.d.ts(1,23): error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'node'.
node_modules/@types/uuid/interfaces.d.ts(4,48): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Buffer'.
node_modules/@types/uws/index.d.ts(7,23): error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'node'.
node_modules/@types/uws/index.d.ts(10,23): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'http'.
node_modules/@types/uws/index.d.ts(11,24): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'https'.
node_modules/@types/uws/index.d.ts(12,22): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'net'.
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "module": "system",
    "strict": true,
    "outFile": "../../lib/client/red5.js",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": true
  },
  "include": [
    "./Connector.ts",
    "**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

dependencies in **package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
  "@types/get-port": "^3.2.0",
  "@types/node": "^10.0.0",
  "@types/uuid": "^3.4.3",
  "@types/uws": "^0.13.2",
  "get-port": "^3.2.0",
  "uuid": "^3.2.1",
  "uws": "^9.148.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "uglify-es": "^3.3.9"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the Node.js 10 changelog, `URL` and `URLSearchParams` are now available globally to mimic the environment found in browsers:

https://github.com/nodejs/node/commit/312414662b

So my bet is that the types definitions `@types/node` are not yet up to date to properly take this change into account.

Comment: I just rolled back my types to `@types/node@9.6.1`, and switched my node version and it fixed it.